# Incrementing nested list in multiprocessing manager

Tags: python

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()

managerdict = manager.dict()

managerdict["first"]= {"stat" : [0,1]}

managerdict["first"]["stat"][0] += 1
managerdict["first"]["stat"][1] += 1

print(managerdict)

anotherdict = {}
anotherdict['foo'] = {"stat" : [0, 1]}
anotherdict['foo']["stat"][0] += 1
anotherdict['foo']["stat"][1] += 1

print(anotherdict)
```

Which outputs:

{'first': {'stat': [0, 1]}}
{'foo': {'stat': [1, 2]}}

What am I doing wrong?

The First entry never gets incremented.
Whereas a normal dict does.

I have tried various other entities like switching the nested list to a nested dict.All the same.

Seems to be an old known issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue6766

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `manager.dict()` has some tricks to monitor item assignments (i.e. directly getting, setting, deleting keys of the dict)

But, as you found out, they aren't able to watch for changes to nested data structures within the managed dict.

This suggests you need to do something like this:

```py
# get a reference to the data structure you want to update
inner_data = managerdict["first"]
# update the data
inner_data["stat"][0] += 1
inner_data["stat"][1] += 1
# assign it back to the managed dict:
managerdict["first"] = inner_data
# now you can observe it updated
print(managerdict)

{'first': {'stat': [1, 2]}}
```